# Shift invariant subspaces

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

For $\phi(z)=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}~,~\alpha\in \mathbb{D}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk, Let us define the operator $M_{\phi}:H^{2}(\mathbb{D})\rightarrow H^{2}(\mathbb{D})$ as $M_{\phi}(f)=\phi f$. If $W$ is a closed subspace of $H^{2}(\mathbb{D})$ invariant under $M_{\phi}$, then what is characterisation of $W$ ?

I am thinking since we know the form of $W$ in the case of multiplication operator by coordinate function $M_{z}$, then we can use the disk automorphism define by $\phi$ to convert the operator $M_{\phi}$ to $M_{w}$, where $w=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$ and then use the result of shift invariant subspace of $M_{w}$ to go back into $M_{\phi}$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Looks ok to me.  It would be even better if you could translate your argument in terms of an invertible operator conjugating $M_\phi$ to $M_w$.

Comment: Thanks Ruy. Can I do that with composition operator?

Comment: I believe that should work.